# Python object as an optional argument of a class instructor

Tags: python, object, optional-arguments

When creating a new instance (say A) of a class, I want an instance (say B) of another class to be an optional argument of the constructor. If B is given as an argument, then I want the constructor of A to specify that B belongs to A. If not given as an argument, I want my constructor to create a NEW instance (say C) of the same class as where B belong to and specify that this new instance belongs to A.

More specifically, I'm working on an arrival process for a hospital. Arrivals happen according to a stochastic process. I want it to be possible to specify whether an `arrival` event is regarding an already existing `customer` (in this case, I should give it as an argument) or that it is going to be a NEW `customer`, in which case my `arrival` constructor should create a new instance of `customer.`

Comment: why should the class `B` care if the customer is new or existing? if it represents a customer that should be sufficient, and `B` can have an attribute indicating whether or not it is a new customer

Comment: Class `B`, doesn't care, `A` does.

Comment: so have some attribute on `B` that indicates if it's new and you can have `A` check for that with a method, I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: can't you just make `B` a member of `A`?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. The thing is that it customers are only defined once they get into the system of the hospital. Customers arrive to a doctor according to some random process, SOME of them get back to that same doctor after service. For the last ones, I want to schedule a new `arrival` for that particular `customer`. In the case where a `customer` is totally new, I should create a new instance.

Comment: @DSC, that's gonna be difficult since I need it in several other classes.

Comment: I'm confused on how that wouldn't work? `A` can then access B but other classes can also do that since the member of `A` just points to the object of `B`

Comment: Maybe it is more clear with the new edit of the question. Sorry.

Comment: I still believe my solution is viable. let me post the code snippet and let me know what you think. If it's not what you meant, i'll just delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b=None):
        if b is None:
            self.b = B()
        else:
            self.b = b
```

Comment: doesn't he want also check if its known or not?

Comment: If no argument is passed to A, it's not known. Otherwise it is.

Comment: @user8426627, no this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

*Arrivals happen according to a stochastic process. I want it to be possible to specify whether an arrival event is regarding an already existing customer (in this case, I should give it as an argument) or that it is going to be a NEW customer, in which case my arrival constructor should create a new instance of customer.*

it is just usage of dict and setdefault:

```
customers = {}

for co in all_customers:

known_customer = customers.setdefault(hash(co), customer(co))
```

or if you do want to have it as constructor:

```
class arrival:

known_cos = {}# quasi static

def __init__(self, co)

  self.customer = known_cos.setdefault(hash(co) , customer(co))
```